# Knockout: Binding to a select-observable returns nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

While following example 3 in this Knockout-example: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

I have a lists of sport-objects I select via a dropdown. Each sport-object has a list of categories which I iterate over based on which sport is selected. This currently works.

Now, I need to get the name of the sport currently selected so I can use it in CRUD-operations. In the example below I try to store it in a hidden field which does not work as intended, leaving the value-attribute in the field empty.

So, how can I get the name (or any other observable in the model) from the selected value in the dropdown?

The code below shows the models and the html I use:

```
    <select id="categorySelector" class="form-control" data-bind="options: Sports, optionsText: 'Name', value: SelectedSport"></select>
    <table  data-bind="foreach: SelectedSport">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Categories">
            <tr data-bind="attr: { 'data-name': Name }">
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $root.SelectedSport.Name" />
    <span data-bind="text: SelectedSport.Name"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        var CategoryModel = function (name) {
            var self = this;
            self.Name = ko.observable(name);
        };
        var SportModel = function (name) {
            var self = this;
            self.Name = ko.observable(name);
        };
        var ViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.Sports = ko.observableArray();
            self.SelectedSport = ko.observable();

            self.GetSports = function () {
                $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (sportIndex, sportValue) {
                        if (sportValue.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
                            var newSport = new SportModel(sportValue.name);
                            console.log(sportValue.name);
                            $.each(sportValue.categories, function (categoryIndex, categoryValue) {
                                if (categoryValue.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
                                    newSport.Categories.push(new CategoryModel(categoryValue.name));
                                    console.log('--' + categoryValue.name);
                                }
                            });
                            self.Sports.push(newSport);
                        }
                    });
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    console.log("Failed to load and/or parse bikeData.json");
                });
            };
        };
        var viewModel = new ViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        viewModel.GetSports();
    </script>
```

The Json file:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Archery",
        "categories": [
            { "name": "Världsmästerskap" },
            { "name": "Vintermästerskap" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Bike",
        "categories": [
            { "name": "Världsmästerskap" },
            { "name": "Europamästerskap" }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: could you please provide jsfiddle

Comment: provide `optionsValue:Name` then `SelectedSport` should have your drop down selected sport i.e try self.SelectedSport() --> gives you Bike if you selected so . simply  <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $root.SelectedSport" /> . cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: you need to check if there really is a value selected and if there isn't, insert a default, like so:

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: SelectedSport() ? SelectedSport().Name : 'unknown'" />
```

The example on the Knockout-site showed this.